# How to fix "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database AnimeFigurineCollection was not found. "

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

How can I fix this? This is my code so far

```
package case_study_3;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CollectionRepository {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection conn;

    public CollectionRepository() {
    
    try {
        dbconn();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CollectionRepository.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CollectionRepository.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CollectionRepository.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    }

   public void dbconn() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AnimeFigurineCollection [wimmy on WIMMY]";
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"wimmy","1231");

    }//end db conn
    
    public List<Collection> getAllProduct(){
        List<Collection> col = new ArrayList<>();
        
        String queryStr = "Select * From ALBUM";
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Collection collect = new Collection(rs.getString("code"),
                    rs.getInt("registrationNumber"),
                    rs.getInt("barcode"),
                    rs.getString("maincharName"),
                    rs.getString("title"),
                    rs.getString("version"),
                    rs.getString("type"));
            col.add(collect);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CollectionRepository.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    
    
    }    
    return col;
    
}//end getall
```

Also when I add my derbyclient.jar this appears:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database AnimeFigurineCollection [wimmy on WIMMY] was not found. ""ERROR 08004: The connection was refused because the database AnimeFigurineCollection [wimmy on WIMMY] was not found."

If I remove it, those two disappears also.

Comment: Are you sure your database is called `AnimeFigurineCollection [wimmy on WIMMY]`, and not for example `AnimeFigurineCollection`?

Comment: is there a difference if the [wimmy on WIMMY] is there or not, im sorry im new in database i still dont know my way around database

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have created a database named `AnimeFigurineCollection`

Comment: They aren't trying to connect to a database called `AnimeFigurineCollection`, but one called `AnimeFigurineCollection [wimmy on WIMMY]`, which is likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: it is generally recommended to avoid using spaces in the names of databases and other database objects. Although some database management systems allow the use of spaces, this practice can cause problems in many situations, such as creating SQL scripts, integrating with other tools, and portability between different systems.